# auto creation of aws iot thing and attaching it to a thing group

Tags: python-3.x, aws-iot

- I have created thing , certificates , policy and attached them successfully using python.
- And i have founded a idea that instead of creating a policy for every new thing that is created , **we can create a thing group and create a policy for that group and adding the thing to it and then  share that group policy to every new thing we created**.
- I didn't have any idea on how to implement my idea and i keeps on searching for a reference to do that still i didn't find any usefull links or guides.If you know anything post that

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone after a long search i find the solution.

```
def add_thing_to_thing_group():
    client = boto3.client('iot')
    thing_group_name ='your thing group name'
    thing_group_arn ='your thing group arn'
    thing_name ='your thing name'
    thing_arn ='your thing arn'
    client.add_thing_to_thing_group(
    thingGroupName= thing_group_name,
    thingGroupArn= thing_group_arn,
    thingName= thing_name,
    thingArn= thing_arn
    )
```

- need boto3 package
- thing group arn and thing arn are available in aws iot console